# Removing trailing whitespaces same as vim

Tags: shell, command-line

Based on this vimcast I changed my .vimrc file.

http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tidying-whitespace#highlighter_963342

Now every single time I touch a file that file has a number of changes related to trailing whitespaces. In one single sweep I want to remove all the trailing whitespaces.

It is trickier though.

Make sure that you don't remove end of line character. vim code takes care of that.

if a line does not have trailing whitespace then that line should not be marked as changed by git.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a hard time interpreting your question -- not sure where git enters in -- but assuming you're looking for a shell command to remove trailing whitespace from each line:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\+$//'
```

To visually confirm that it's removing whitespace:

```
cat -E afile
sed 's/[[:space:]]\+//' afile | cat -E
```

Answer (score 1):

git config --global apply.whitespace nowarn

http://help.github.com/git-cheat-sheets/